# 1 div Left and 2 divs right?

Tags: html, markup

I am creating a header with the image logo in a left div (100px height) and 2 seperate stacked right divs (50px Height each) on the for menu and info.

I want the header to be 100px Height.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Russ, click "edit"  under your question and paste your code. Otherwise your question will be closed soon.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try any code as of yet... However, Turtle has helped, but I need the right divs to be stacked over each other

Comment: I am a newbie here and somewhat green to coding. This was my first post here... Now I am being penalized? Now just because I didn't post what little code I didn't have I can't ask another question? I have been working on this all day and didn't have any code to even try. Could you guys please retract your negative feedback please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put together a little pen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vXwvZr

You need to give each html id and set `minimum-height`. You can then `float` the elements left to have them line up next to each other.

Hope this helps and please next time post your code.

Comment: I am a novice but learning a lot.. per your response, I would like the green and yellow under/over one another

Comment: @Russ As you know the height and widths you're working with you could give an element the position of relative and then adjust as required. 

Here is a pen showing the updates http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEmYJY

Comment: @Russ Happy to help. Please mark my answer if it helped you and answered your question. Thanks.